# Как сделать ActionBar?

Tags: android, java

Как сделать вот такой `ActionBar`? Желательно в виде Java-кода, а не XML-разметки.

[image]

Я только начал разбираться и написал простой код:

```
MyActivity extends Activity {
  @Override 
  public void onCreate(Bundle bundle) { 
    super.onCreate(bundle); 

    ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar(); 
    actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText("Test")); 
  } 
}
```

Метод `getActionBar` всегда возвращает `Null`. Почему?

Comment: А какая версия апи используется?
Из доки:
"public ActionBar getActionBar ()

Since: API Level 11
Retrieve a reference to this activity's ActionBar.
Returns

The Activity's ActionBar, or null if it does not have one."

Comment: Судя по скриншоту то АПИ-левел как минимум 11 должен быть.

Comment: Я не знаю :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

На самом деле никаких хитростей здесь не нужно делать. Благодаря тому, что в манифесте будет включен АПИ-левел > 11 андроид автоматически будет формировать экшн-бар.
Оформляете меню обычным способом

```
@Override public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
  MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
  inflater.inflate(R.menu.main_activity, menu);
  return true;
}
```

и файл с описанием меню

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item android:id="@+id/menu_save"
      android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_save"
      android:title="@string/menu_save"
      android:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText" />
</menu>
```

и будет вам экшн-бар.
Основной момент здесь - это различные вариации аттрибута android:showAsAction. С его помощью можно настраивать отображение отдельного пункта меню (пункт меню, кнопка экшн-бара с картинкой/без картинки etc.)
Выбор элемента отлавливается в стандартном коллбеке.

И да, подробнее можно узнать здесь [ActionBar on developer.android.com](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html)

Comment: А API Level указывается так?

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="11" />

Comment: да, все верно