# Запуск на устройствах с ранними версиями SDK

Tags: android, java

В продолжение темы "[Как сделать ActionBar?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/67552/%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-actionbar)". Я сделал всё, как там посоветовали. И теперь интересно, можно ли как-то сделать, чтобы если устройство не поддерживает этот уровень SDK (в данном случае 11), то просто не отображать `ActionBar` или отображать его как-то по-другому, как делали в ранних версиях. А то сейчас на таких устройствах вообще нельзя запустить приложение.

P.S. В манифест добавлял

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="11"
          android:targetSdkVersion="11"/>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Да можно. Надо организовать ветвление в коде по значению переменной `android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT`, предварительно естественно поставив `minSdkVersion` во что нибудь типа 4-6

Answer (score 1):

Можно. Посмотрите [этот пример](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ActionBarCompat/index.html) с оффициальной документации.
Если есть желание и возможность можно еще посмотреть на [ActionBarSherlock](http://actionbarsherlock.com/). Сам правда его пока не использовал, но слышал лестные отзывы от трудящихся.

Answer (score 1):

Пересоздай проект под версию 1.5 и будет запускаться везде